# Regex to match XML Group

Tags: regex, xml

Just as a disclaimer, I just want to do this to make my life easier when reading logs.. Sometimes they have more than 100mb of text

I want to match a XML Group in which it contains some data.

Suppose I have a XML like below (and they are in the same line):

```
<car><id>1</id><acquiredDate>23-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>
<car><id>2</id><acquiredDate>23-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>
<car><id>3</id><acquiredDate>24-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>
<car><id>4</id><acquiredDate>23-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>
```

I want to match all cars that have were acquired on 23-09-2016. (3 matches on this case)

What I have so far is `<car>.*?<acquiredDate>23-09-2016<\/acquiredDate>.*?<\/car>`, but it will match the third and fourth car together.
Something like:

`<car><id>1</id><acquiredDate>23-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>`

`<car><id>2</id><acquiredDate>23-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>`

`<car><id>3</id><acquiredDate>24-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car><car><id>4</id><acquiredDate>23-09-2016</acquiredDate><model>BMW</model></car>`

I tried using something like `<car>(?!.*<car>.*).*?<acquiredDate>23-09-2016<\/acquiredDate>.*?<\/car>` but it will match only the last.

How I achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: please read my disclaimer. as the second answer says `it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML`. that's what I want

Comment: `<\/acquiredDate>.*?<\/car>` Why do you use `.*?` between the tags when your example shows nothing in-between them?

Comment: sorry about that @JesseGood.. the real case has data between.. let me update the question

Comment: @FelipeS. I read your disclaimer - it's still easier to use a DOM method like `getElementsByTagName('acquiredDate')` and read the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @MacroMan I'm using just to search data.. how do I use `getElementsByTagName` in `less`, `grep` or something similar ? :/

Comment: But can you use lookarounds at least? I see you are using it, just to confirm.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew lookarounds would be fine! I just couldn't make it work properly..

Comment: It is a bit strange, since [your regex works](https://regex101.com/r/jK0xM0/1) if the `.` does not match a newline and the strings are on separate lines. If I use a dotall modifier, I get [the same behavior](https://regex101.com/r/jK0xM0/2) you describe.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest [`<car>(?:(?!<(?:car|acquiredDate)>).)*<acquiredDate>23-09-2016<\/acquiredDate>.*?<\/car>`](https://regex101.com/r/jK0xM0/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would you know how to fix my regex using dotall modifier?

Comment: Yeah, I posted my suggestion above. But MacroMan's pattern might work as well with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to go down the regex-matching-html route, then assuming you want to match the whole line, something like this would work:

```
/(?:^\<car\>[<\w>\/]+acquiredDate\>)(23\-09\-2016)(?:.+$)/gm
                                     ^^  ^^  ^^^^ 
                                 (change as required)
```

Comment: This is exactly the match I needed! Sorry for being insistent in the regex thing.. It's because I'll use to find some text in a giant log. Now I can find my bugs !! thanks!

Comment: @FelipeS. just to be clear, I'm not preaching about _not using regex_ (notice I didn't downvote your question - it's a perfectly good and valid question to ask) it's just that using a parser can make life easier. Ultimately whatever works for you is the right way so it's your preference.